# visual studio 2012 asp.net HTTPpost data to db error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, models

When using following code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert";
    Layout = "../_Insert.cshtml";
    model Namespace.GoogleCalendarModel
}

<label>Kies een evenement</label>
<select>
    @foreach (var e in ViewBag.allEvents)
    {
        <option value="@e.Id">@e.Titel</option>
    }
</select>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert","GoogleCalendar", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <label>Formuleer werksfeer</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtModus);
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Formuleer de opdrachten</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtOpdrachten);
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Formuleer mededeling</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtMededeling);
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.toevoegen);
}
```

i get following error on model Namespace.GoogleCalendarModel:
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

anybody an idea of how to fix this? Or a working example for an httppost for writing data to db in MVC asp.net visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model must be specified using `@model`:

```
@model Namespace.GoogleCalendarModel  //notice there's no semicolon at the end

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert";
    Layout = "../_Insert.cshtml";
}
```

You are not assigning anything since `model` (notice lowercase first letter) is not a variable. You can consider it as a construct similar to the `using` keyword for adding namespaces.

Comment: thanks but that actually did work, it's about the model Namespace GoogleCalendarModel, sorry wasn't clear in my question

Comment: @model thegymCalendar.Models.apiEvents;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert";
    Layout = "../_Insert.cshtml";
}

i did that but still same error..

Comment: @Sesamzaad, please notice I didn't write `;` at the end of the `@model` declaration. As far as I can tell from your comment, you are writing `;` and that usualy generates the error.

Comment: But i'm still not able to add this data into my database for some reason.. 
i have my class apiEvents: 
http://pastie.org/private/mm98rdmyubgcamvpbm5ww
my controller AppController:
http://pastie.org/private/ef37mddqcfysnahkbwmllg
and my view: 
http://pastie.org/private/arpvpbjvtdrtcc5rzn4mia

i generate an error on eventm.insert(gymevent);
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'thegymCalendar.Models.apiEvents' to 'thegymCalendar.Models.GoogleCalendar'

Comment: @Sesamzaad, I can't really say where things are going wrong. You should try debugging: add a break point in your `Insert` post action and see if the returned object contains all the right data; if the data is posted correctly, there's a problem with your `eventm.insert(gymevent);`; if not, there's a problem in the view.